When I start scrapy crawl, it occured timeout. How can I solve this problem?
I use v2ray in Linux, and configure system proxy in ~/.bachrc
When I start scrapy crawl
it occured timeout
2024-09-10 15:51:54 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://douban.com> (failed 1 times): User timeout caused connection failure: Getting https://douban.com took longer than 180.0 seconds..
The same situation occured in selenium. How can I solve this problem？
